# Visual studio - ASP.NET Core React JS template not starting properly

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2019

I am creating a new ASP.NET Core with React JS using Visual Studio 2019. .net version is 5.

The project is created successfully. When I run the project (F5), it loads this url: https://localhost:44390/ but nothing works, I get this message:

> This site can’t be reachedThe connection was reset.
>
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection
> Checking the proxy and the firewall
>
> Running Windows Network Diagnostics ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

If I go to the ClientApp folder directly, and run npm start, it will load the client side app on http://localhost:3000 but the "Fetch Data" tab will not work.

Basically the web api itself isn't working. Any idea?
Is it something related to it being https?

I am just using the default ReactJS template in the IDE.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Would it be possible for your to upload your project to github, so we can clone and reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

guess you have already solved it but, I hit the same problem. It went down to Node version I was using.

I was using 12.14.0

[nvm list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdZim.png)

The only thing I had to do is to use a more recent version 18.x.x or 17.x.x

After that when I started the project, with F5 from VS, it started successfully.

Hope this will help others that also hit that problem

Happy coding